# docker compose in bitbucket - Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitbucket-pipelines, azure-container-instances

I want to deploy container group to Azure Container Instances from bitbucket pipelines. I have following `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file:

```
image: ubuntu:20.04

clone:
  depth: 5

options:
  max-time: 15

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to aci
          deployment: test
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get install curl -y
            - curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose-cli/main/scripts/install/install_linux.sh | sh
            - curl -sSL https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/releases/download/v2.0.0-beta.3/docker-compose-linux-amd64 -o docker-compose
            - chmod +x docker-compose
            - mkdir -p ~/.docker/cli-plugins
            - mv docker-compose ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
            - docker login azure --client-id $CLIENTID --tenant-id $TENANTID --client-secret $SECRET
            - docker login myregistry.azurecr.io -u $USERNAME -p $PASS 
            - docker context create aci myContext --subscription-id "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" --resource-group "myResouceGroup" --location "westeurope"
            - docker --context myContext compose up 
      services:
        - docker
```

I am getting following error on `docker --context myContext compose up` command:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

All other docker command seems to be working so it's seems to be problem with docker-compose cli that it doesn't find the deamon running.

I tried adding `export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"` before `docker compose up` but it didn't help.

Is there something I am missing?

**UPDATE 1:**

If I update last command from:

```
- docker --context myContext compose up
```

To:

```
- docker context use myContext 
- docker compose up
```

I am getting different error:
`failed to dial gRPC: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing unable to upgrade to h2c, received 403"`

**UPDATE 2**

Added `docker version` and `docker ps` for more info. Output:

`docker version`

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           19.03.15
 API version:       1.40
 ...

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  ...
```

`docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Comment: add `docker -v`  and `docker ps` at the beginning of your scripts step. I think your problem is with docker, not with docker-compose

Comment: Added. Those seem to return info that docker in running fine.

Comment: My solution was not to use `docker-compose` and move to Azure Kubernetes Service

Answer (score 1):

For all poor souls who found only this link while searching for

```
failed to get status: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing unable to upgrade to h2c, received 403"
```

the solution is to add step

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
```

just before starting

```
docker compose up
```

here's the reference on the [bitbucket site](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/docker-buildkit-error-in-pipelines-1235859715.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Is the docker daemon running?** is a common error caused by s.o permissions, docker-in-docker, etc. Also this error is not related to docker-compose.

In your case, you are executing docker commands inside of a docker container, so try to add this at the beginning of your pipeline:

```
options:
  docker: true
```

Check these solutions for **Is the docker daemon running?** error:

- [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:/var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker)
- [How to connect to docker daemon in Bitbucket pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67126094/how-to-connect-to-docker-daemon-in-bitbucket-pipeline)
- https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/535
- https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-the-docker-daemon-running-on-this-host/8925

Also I advice to try with a **basic docker commands** (simple build or run) before docker context with docker-compose configurations. For example, a lot of users notify the same error (Is the docker daemon running?) when one of these commands are executed:

- docker info
- docker run ...
- docker ps

Comment: I have enabled docker with another command. See last two lines of my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file. (Those should produce the same result). I also executed `docker version` and `docker ps` and updated my question with result of those commands. I also tried buiding docker image and it worked fine, so the only thing that is not working is `docker-compose`